# after I created multiple models in my django app for the restframwork I start getting more errs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rest

I created a single model django project then I added tow more models then I got this err

```
RecursionError at /elements/
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

then I reinstalled some packages like djangorestframwork-recursion, then I got this err

```
Error at /
Incorrect padding
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: Error
Exception Value:    
Incorrect padding
Exception Location: //anaconda3/lib/python3.7/base64.py in b64decode, line 87
Python Executable:  //anaconda3/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/apple/Desktop/Trying to clone notionso note taking app with django '
 'and reac1/backend/restapi',
 '//anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '//anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
 '//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/apple/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa']
Server time:    Fri, 7 Aug 2020 06:59:57 +0000
```

also when I ran python manage.py makemigrations i got

```
You are trying to change the nullable field 'text' on components to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
 3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

what is the problem with the `nullable field 'text'` (also I change every `null=Flase` to `null=True` i got the same err.

models.py

```
# this is a recursive model
from django.db import models


class elements(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    src = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    # problem: styles replace spaces with slashes (/)
    # I tried: json field but did'nt work.
    style = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    main = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub", on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class styles(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    style = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    main = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub", on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class components(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    tag = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    src = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    style = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    main = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

serialzers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models.models import elements, styles, components
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField


class elementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub = RecursiveField(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = elements
        fields = ('id', 'tag', 'text', 'src', 'style', 'main', 'sub')


class stylesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub = RecursiveField(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = styles
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'style', 'main', 'sub')


class componentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub = RecursiveField(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = components
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tag', 'text', 'src', 'style', 'main', 'sub')
```

view.py

```
from models.models import elements, styles, components
from .serializers import elementsSerializer, stylesSerializer, componentsSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class elementsVeiwSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = elementsSerializer
    queryset = elements.objects.all()


class stylesVeiwSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = stylesSerializer
    queryset = styles.objects.all()


class componentsVeiwSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = componentsSerializer
    queryset = components.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
from models.models import elements, styles, components
from .serializers import elementsSerializer, stylesSerializer, componentsSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class elementsVeiwSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = elementsSerializer
    queryset = elements.objects.all()


class stylesVeiwSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = stylesSerializer
    queryset = styles.objects.all()


class componentsVeiwSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = componentsSerializer
    queryset = components.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)**
I am not sure why you have this field in each of your models

```
main = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I think this is the reason for your recursion problem. Try removing it.

**2)** Regarding your problem with the nullable Field `text` it is because you did not provide a default value (you have to do that because you did not allow it to be Null). You do it like that:

```
text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False, default='')
```

Comment: the best idea for my case is to recreate the project -_-

Comment: @AliHusham That's not needed at all, and it won't change anything. The only thing you should remove when you are really stuck are your migration files. And in the worst case you delete your database and migrate from scratch.

Comment: I find out the I set the env folder inside the .gitignore so it is environment issue and I'm a beginner. Also, how can I delete my migrations? or the data of the sql?

Comment: Yes your env should be in gitignore. But that will not remove it in your local project-files. You can delete your migrations by deleting all files (except `__init__.py`) under your app's directory `migrations`. To delete your database simply remove the file (for example the `db.sqlite3` file.